# MySQL simple procedure error

Tags: mysql

i want to make simple procedure for insert in table. Here is my code:

```
create procedure dodajKorisnika
(
    IN p_ime varchar(15),
    IN p_prezime varchar(15),
    IN p_broj_telefona int,
    IN p_datum_rodjenja date,
    IN p_broj_vozacke int,
    IN p_grad_id int
)
BEGIN




    INSERT into korisnik(
    ime,
    prezime,
    broj_telefona,
    datum_rodjenja,
    broj_vozacke,
    grad_id)
     VALUES(
    p_ime,
    p_prezime,
    p_broj_telefona,
    p_datum_rodjenja,
    p_broj_vozacke,
    p_grad_id
    );

END
```

http://prntscr.com/7u7eia
When i go maous over underline part i got notification Syntax error:missing 'semicolon'
When i try to run Query i got error 1064.

Comment: The last END needs a ;.
THen to get it running add **DELIMITER #** before create procedure, and **DELIMITER ;** after the last END;

Comment: Thx dude, its work, i made it, now ill try tu run it

Comment: Yes, the first stored procedure is a big hurdle: SQL procedures (functions,triggers) tend to be bit counter intuitive compared many other programming languages.

Comment: procedure called, thx again :)

Comment: Here i'm again, now i just add to check does user have 18 years, and again, same error, now is underline last delimiter.

Comment: if(TIMESTAMPDIFF(p_datum_rodjenja,CURDATE()) >18) then

Comment: Can you update your post with the exact code you are using now? That makes it a bit more clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure should look like this:

```
drop procedure if exists dodajKorisnika;
DELIMITER ;;
create procedure dodajKorisnika
(
    IN p_ime varchar(15),
    IN p_prezime varchar(15),
    IN p_broj_telefona int,
    IN p_datum_rodjenja date,
    IN p_broj_vozacke int,
    IN p_grad_id int
)
BEGIN

    INSERT into korisnik(
    ime,
    prezime,
    broj_telefona,
    datum_rodjenja,
    broj_vozacke,
    grad_id)
     VALUES(
    p_ime,
    p_prezime,
    p_broj_telefona,
    p_datum_rodjenja,
    p_broj_vozacke,
    p_grad_id
    );

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The reason of using delimiter is:

> To change the default MySQL script parser’s delimiter from semicolon
>   (;) to double-semicolan sign (;;). The reason you do this is so that
>   the semicolons after each statement in the body of the routine are not
>   interpreted by the parser as meaning the end of the CREATE PROCEDURE
>   statement. This is because the entire CREATE PROCEDURE block, from
>   CREATE PROCEDURE to END is actually a single statement that must be
>   executed by itself. Were it not for the delimiter change, the script
>   would break, since there each statement inside BEGIN and END would
>   execute individually. **Note that you can use a variety of non-reserved
>   characters to make your own custom delimiter.**

And the `drop procedure` is to drop the existing routine, if it exists.

Hope this helps.